# Android Notification.Builder addAction PendingIntent Fragment

Tags: android, notifications, fragment

I have a mainActivity that has 4 fragments (A, B, C and D).  If Fragment B is an audio player that allows for audio to be played in the back ground, and places a Notification in the action bar that the audio is playing, and the user then navigates via a drawer to Fragment C; If the user goes to their home screen and then swipes down to get to the Notifications, and clicks no the apps notification, what do I catch in mainActivity such that when the app is brought back to the foreground that it switches to Fragment B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put extra into the intent to describe which fragment to open.
For example if you want B to be opened you can do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragment_name", "B");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and then get the extra inside your activity with

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("fragment_name");
```

Comment: Thanks @Niko Yuwono; where do I catch the getIntent?  Is this in the onResume of MainActivity that I would then re-create the B Fragment and Intent to it?

Comment: Yes I think you can catch it in the onResume of MainActivity and do the Fragment transaction there too

Comment: Thanks @Niko Yuwono; However I'm getting an crash when I execute the fragment while still inside the onResume.

Comment: So Sorry @Niko Yuwono, the error was un initialized variable.  your code worked! Thanks!

Comment: @justdan0227 Glad that I can help!